# Vue JS - Loop through a computed property to display a list of years

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, computed-properties

I currently have the following code that lists a list of years. I feel that all this code may be very unnecessary and perhaps a computed property for validYears, would help me make this code more optimal and get rid of the unnecessary watchers. My issue is converting this to a computed property as I'm failing to grasp the correct logic to achieve this. I'd appreciate if someone can offer an example of how I can set a computed property for valid years and still return the same result.

```
    onBeforeMount(calculateDateRange)

    watch(() => props.earliestDate, (newValue, prevValue) => {
      calculateDateRange();
    });
    // If there is a new value passed from the parent, the dropdown should display that new value.
    watch(() => props.latestDate, (newValue, prevValue) => {
      calculateDateRange()
    });

    const validYears = ref([])
    function calculateDateRange () {
      for(let year = props.latestDate; year >= props.earliestDate; year--){
        validYears.value.push(year)
      }
    }
```

I didn't provide the rest of the code not to clutter the question, but as one can see in this component I have a set of props that determine the values in my for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could optimize it as follows :

```
const validYears = computed(()=>{
    let _years=[]
    for(let year = props.latestDate; year >= props.earliestDate; year--){
        _years.push(year)
      }
 
  return _years;

})
```